# PowerShell Script to empty recycle bin works locally but not remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have the following PowerShell script to empty the recycle bin.

```
$recycleBin = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace(0xa)
$recycleBin.Items() | ForEach-Object -Process { Remove-Item -Path $_.Path -Force -Recurse }
```

The script works locally on my machine. I want to invoke the same script remotely, but it does not work. This script is meant to empty the recycle bin of the (primary) user that is signed in, and the machine has only C drive. 
 I have been invoking remotely many other scripts like removing temporary files of browsers, getting system info, etc. They all work fine. 
I am using System.Management.Automation library to invoke the script and I add the remote machine details and admin credentials needed to the Runspace. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) you can find details about the library.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: I believe recycle bins are both drive and profile-specific. How are you invoking and how are you specifying the profile/drive?

Comment: Update your question to include details on how you are trying to run this remotely.

Comment: There is also a script already written which will do what you need: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RecycleBinSize-092f15c7

Comment: @notjustme  I just updated the question. @Scepticalist the user has only C drive. The user's computer name is added to connectionInfo which is an object of type `WSManConnectionInfo`  .  I have seen that script, but it is too much complex for my task. I only want to empty the recycle bin where the script is being executed while the user is signed in to that computer.

Comment: You're referring and linking to the documentation of a well known class instead of showing us how you are implementing it. It would be a lot more useful if you included the code of your implementation. The part about the target profile that @Scepticalist mentioned is quite crucial in this scenario.